# How to include two class files at the same time in PHP, so that their methods are accessible between each other?

Tags: php, class, oop, include

I have something like the following:

```
include 'firstclass.php';
include 'secondclass.php';
```

`firstclass.php`:

```
class First {
  public static function foo() {
    Second::bar();
  }
  public static function oof() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

`secondclass.php`:

```
class Second {
  public static function bar() {
    First::oof();
  }
}
```

As can be seen, I need to access the methods of the `Second` class from the `First`, and vice versa.

How can I include both so that they are accessible from each other's classes?

Comment: Look into autoloading of classes: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: @Jaime Ah thanks, that helped me. Perhaps you would like to put more information into an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options:

**Put them in the same file**

The easiest quickest fix is to put both classes in the same file.  PHP parses the whole file before executing it, so the classes will be able to use each other's methods.  This will work, but the more professional and scalable solution is the other option.

**Use autoloading**

PHP allows you to give it instructions on where to look when you invoke an unknown class.  This is called autoloading ([intro](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)).

Have an initialization script that runs before all scripts. This is most easily done by setting `auto_prepend_file=/path/to/init.php` in `php.ini` ([details](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file)).  Once you've setup such a script, you can add autoloading instructions to it

```
//function called whenever you use an unknown class. It will
//be passed the name of your class
function my_autoloader($class) {
    include __DIR__ .'/classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
}

spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');
```

The code above would work if your classes are in a `classes` subdirectory of `init.php`, and use the extension `.class.php`.  So to make it work with your example, your directory structure would need to be

```
init.php
classes/
    First.class.php
    Second.class.php
```

Make adjustments to the autoloader as appropriate.

Comment: Since it is is one `File / Directory`, I will not call `require_once` twice?

Comment: @RoCk `require_once` is never called. Autoloading is different. PHP parses the whole file before executing any of it; when it comes across a class it doesn't know, it will use `my_autoloader` to find it and load it into memory. When you call upon a class that has already been loaded, it will not be re-loaded (`my_autoloader` is not called for known classes).